# Elliptical movement of a rigidbody (as in whale trail game) by applying force in unity using c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to move a rigid body in an elliptical movement like the player movement "whale trail" game.What I did is:

1. Created a Cube called "Player" with scale(1.5,0.5,0.1)
2. Created another small cube called `Point` with scale(0.1,0.1,0.1) and positioned same  as `Player` but 0.5 more in x (So that now the player looks like a 2D rectangle and a point on it little right to the centre of the rectangle).
3. Then I created a fixed joint between both bodies
4. Now I applied for on the player at the position of the Point as follows ,

   ```
   float mfAngle = 0.0f;
   void update()
   {
       mfAngle=transform.eulerAngles.z;
   mfAngle=mfAngle%360;

   if(mfAngle>=0 && mfAngle<90)
   {
       mfXforce=-0.1f;
   mfYforce=0.1f;
   }
   if(mfAngle>=90 && mfAngle<180)
   {
       mfXforce=-0.1f;
   mfYforce=0.1f;
       }
   if(mfAngle>=180 && mfAngle<270)
   {
   mfXforce=-0.1f;
   mfYforce=-0.1f;
   }
   if(mfAngle>=270 && mfAngle<360)
   {
   mfXforce=0.1f;
   mfYforce=-0.1f;
   }

   Debug.Log("Angle ="+mfAngle+"X = "+mfXforce+"Y = "+mfYforce);

   Vector3 pointPos=_goPointObject.transform.position;
   transform.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(mfXforce,mfYforce,0),pointPos);
   }
   ```

But it doesn't works fine.I just moves upwards and the turns and moves in different direction.If anyone know how to move the rigid body in elliptical motion by applying force give me a solution.(I want to use it as like whale trail game u can see the video of the "loop movement" in this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwr6c2Ws1yI video).Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work fine? What happens if you run the game with the code you provided?

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution by myself.To achieve that elliptical movement u have to create two bodies and connect them with joint by placing it horizontally next to each other.Then u have to apply force in x direction constantly and in Y direction only when the Screen is be touched  on the first body.

And its important to reduce the X speed when moving up then u will get that elliptical rotation.

It works fine for me.

Thanks,
Ashokkumar M